# Why is std::reverse() not reversing the string?

Tags: c++, string, reverse

I am trying to reverse an input sentence word by word. For example :

> Input : This is a sentence

The output should be :

> Output : sentence a is This

So I am using strings in the following code :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    

        std::string sentence("This is a sentence"), rev_sentence;
        char *words = new char[20];
        
        std::cout <<"This is the sentence : "<< sentence << std::endl;
        
        words = strtok(&sentence[0], " "); //Tokenizing
        while (words != NULL)
        {
            rev_sentence.append(words);
            rev_sentence += ' ';
            words = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        rev_sentence.pop_back(); //Removing the last blankspace
        
        std::cout <<"This is before final reverse : " << rev_sentence << std::endl;
        
        std::reverse(rev_sentence.begin(), rev_sentence.end()); //reverse()
        std::cout << rev_sentence << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is fine before `std::reverse()` but it does not print the final output once I call it.
Can anyone specify what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your example leaks memory. I recommend avoiding owning bare pointers.

Comment: Consider this: If you build "one two three" the result of reversing that as a sequence of *characters* is "eerht owt eno" , not "three two one". If you want to reverse the words, then do that; not the entire string. There a multiple ways to do it, the easiest being just reading the words into a deque of strings, pushing each word onto the front, then enumerate the deque when done. Good luck.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but don't mess with `strtok`. It's an abomination. `std::string` has a rich set of member functions for searching the contents of a string.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reverse the characters of a string, as element of `std::string rev_sentence` are characters.

Use a container with string elements, like `std::vector<std::string>` as the source for reverse.